# develop a user defined plugin for web browser

Tags: java, javascript, asp.net, jquery-plugins, applet

How to develop a user defined plugin for a web browser.
It should features:

1. It should be installed in any browsers.
2. It should be executed whenever the browser starts.
3. It should monitor the web page and access the web page that the browser displays.
4. It should monitor and access the web page (for example, getting a value from a text box) irrespective of the web page the browser displays. (The web page can be of any URL either google or any domain)

How to start with it? It would be helpful if there is some sample. Thanks in advance

Comment: Plugin or Addon/Extension? Which Platform? Win/Lin/Mac? "Any browsers" does that included Netscape 4? :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. For Firefox < 4 write an [Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/getting-started), for 4 and above [Jetpack](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/) will be the way to go. For Chrome write a [Extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html). Opera, well wait till 11.5 ships. [Safari 5](http://developer.apple.com/programs/safari/). [IE](http://blogs.msdn.com/petel/archive/2006/11/07/writing-ie-addons.aspx).
2. Read the documentation for each browser.
3. Hm...
4. I hope you tell the user about that.

Right now it reads like you want to deploy something to a PC and monitor all browsers, well if you want to do that you'll have to put some effort into it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think **1.** is possible, you will have to create multiple versions of your plugin in order to work with each browser.

There is not a single example, because as I mentioned, you are going to have to do something different.  You will need to determine and target specific browsers.  I would suggest starting with one and once you have it have it working move to the next browser.

Comment: Actually my need is to develop some plugin/extension/some tool in browser that should start monitoring the web pages whenever the browser starts. I would say it should work like basic functionalities of (page ranking toolbar in browser)

Comment: @user, that still can't be done independent of the browser type.

Comment: Tats fine, it dont need to be independent. It is fine to develop this funsionality for a particular browser

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a Plugin (like Flash, PDF Reader) or and Extension?

Plugins are native programs and extensions are normally coded in JavaScript & HTML.
Depending on what you want to do, an extension is enough powerful and the better choice.

There is no browser independent way to implement plugins. For each browsers you must read the interface reference. For example the reference for chrome: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html

Comment: Actually my need is to develop some plugin/extension/some tool in browser that should start monitoring the web pages whenever the browser starts. I would say it should work like basic functionalities of (page ranking toolbar in browser)

Comment: You can do such a functionality by an extension in the most browsers. But the interface is different in each browser, so you have to read the reference ;)

Comment: Ya Thanks. Can u provide me some article or some stuffs to develop a extension for browser (google chrome)

Comment: I´ve already given you a link to a good tutorial in my Answer. Check it out. It´s quite easy ;)

Comment: Hi i have to get and check the URL displayed in the currrent tab (only one tab found in window) in content-scripts(myscripts.js) ---- used in manifest.json

Comment: you can't access the url in the content script. you must send a request to the background page, which sends the url back to the content script. hope this helps.